# How to disable SELinux without restart?

Tags: rhel, selinux

I need to disable SELinux but cannot restart the machine

i followed [this](http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/redhat/centos-redhat/disable-selinux-without-reboot-on-centos-6-3/) link where i get bellow command

```
setenforce 0
```

But after running this command i checked for that

```
sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          disabled
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Is there any other option?

Comment: `setenforce 0` <- did you run it from root or with `sudo`?

Comment: @UVV yes i am doing all this from root

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`sestatus` is showing the current mode as `permissive`.

In `permissive` mode, SELinux will not block anything, but merely warns you. The line will show `enforcing` when it's actually blocking.

I don't believe it's possible to completely disable SELinux without a reboot.

Comment: I think you can disable it without a reboot by directly editing the /etc/selinux/config file and setting SELINUX=disabled

Comment: @dmohr - If you read [this Centos document](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html) it tells you that it only works on the next reboot.

Answer (score 14):

Disabling `SELinux` without reboot is not possible. But I guess making it in `permissive` mode is going to satifsy your requirement.

The output of `sestatus` shows `SELinux` is enabled but also shows it is in `Permissive` mode, which is what you just did with the `setenforce` command.

Answer (score 11):

On CentOS 7:

```
echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
```

Comment: fwiw, this didn't work for me, Centos 7.2: `# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
# echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
`

Comment: This only disables selinux in current "session" and when rebooting this config will be lost.

Comment: By current "session" I mean current runtime. Also 0 does not disable selinux but configure it as permissive.

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing what OP did should work. On Fedora 26:

```
[aries@csibesz]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

As user doesn't work.

```
[aries@csibesz]$ setenforce 0
setenforce:  setenforce() failed
```

As root, it does:

```
[aries@csibesz]$ sudo setenforce 0
[aries@csibesz]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

The same applies to CentOS 7 and RedHat EL 7: it is working without reboot.

Answer (score 6):

Best way to disable SELinuxis by using following command:

`sed -i 's/enforcing/disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config`

OR

`vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux`, set `selinux=disabled`

OR

`setenforce 0 && sestatus`

Though in certain cases restart will be required.

Answer (score 3):

For CentOS 6 (not 7):

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: Does not work on centos 7. Only works on centos 6 and under

Comment: This answer is correct for centos 6. Please double check before downvoting.